# Convert ArrayBuffer response to JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, arraybuffer

Here I am calling a GetFile , getting response as ArrayBuffer{} object, In network Tab response is {"errors":["photoProof Image is not available in the system"]}, if I do response.errors=undefined.

```
$scope.getDocuments = function(){
  Myservice.downLoadDocument('photo', $scope.user.mobileNo).
    then(function(response){
     })
}
```

If I Do this, getting below this value in Network Tab.

```
 response.byteLength = 64
```

how do I convert  this ArrayBuffer  into proper JSON format?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder):

```
try {
  parsedJson = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(response as ArrayBuffer));
} catch (e) {
  parsedJson = {};
}
```

In my case the request is waiting for an ArrayBuffer response, but if an error occours on the backend, I get a JSON object containing the error. I check if the response is an error with this code.

The try-catch block is needed because if the ArrayBuffer is not a json, then the JSON.parse() method will throw an error.

Answer (score 7):

This wokrs for me :

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(replaceThisByYourData))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maby you can use [json-bufferify](https://github.com/LangZhai/json-bufferify). It's a module to help you convert between JSON and ArrayBuffer, and you can run it in both Node.js and browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Buffer.from(yourArrayBufferValue).toJSON();
```

Although this answer is a little bit late, I hope it helps someone

Comment: this does work only on node dont waste your time if you are using js

Answer (score 2):

```html
var jsonResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
```

will do wonders.