# how intercept and stub the response of a rpc call in react with cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress, grpc

I want to intercept a rpc call that I made to the api in my react app. I'm using a custom hook that receives the buffer and the rpc method that I want to call and returns the data(something like react-query useQuery hook).

The thing is because of being a rpc call, the request urls of my requests are all the same and the response is binary, I can't distinguish the requests and intercept the one to stub.

One example of making a rpc call:

```js
const {response, loading, error} = useRpc({
   Buffer: GetUser,
   Request: GetUserRequest
});
```

---

**Edit 1:**
I'm using

```js
cy.fixture('fixutre-file').then((data) => {
   const response = new TextDecoder().decode(res.body);

cy.intercept('https://example.com/', { method: 'POST' }, 
  (req) => {
    req.continue((res) => {
       if ("some condition for distinguishing the request I want to intercept, here") {
          res.send({ fixture: 'fixutre-file' });
       }
    });
  });
}):
```

to get the response and decide whether or not intercept this req and instead send back my fixture data. But the `response` constant is still some unreadable string. What's wrong with my approach?

---

**Edit 2:**
Another approach that I used, was to use the `cypress-protobuf` package and encode my fixture.json file with the related protobuffer file:

```js
cy.fixture('fixutre-file').then((data) => {
   cy.task('protobufEncode', {
        fixtureBody: data,
        message: 'the_message',
        protoFilePath: './protobuf/protofile.proto'
      }).then((encodedData) => {
cy.intercept('https://example.com/', { method: 'POST' }, 
  (req) => {
        /////// approach 1(didn't work): ///////
        // can't use this approach(because there is no identifier on 
        // req object to distinguish the requests I want to 
        // intercept)
        // if ("some condition based on `req` here") {
        //   req.reply(encodedData);
        // } else {
        //   req.continue();
        // }
         
        /////// approach 2: ///////
        // using encodedData to compare it with res.body
        req.continue(res => {
           // can't compare res.body with encodedData, because 
           // encodedData is an empty string!
        });
     }).as('needToWait');

     cy.wait('@needToWait').get('some selector').should('exist')
  });
}):
```

Now the problem is:
`encodedData` is just an empty string, meaning it didn't work, so I can't compare the response with my fixture data to intercept the related request

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for some value from the request that distinguishes it from the other requests. Request bodies and headers are often good places to start. Additionally, [you can use `req.alias`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests) to conditionally assign an alias if you need to wait for that specific call.

```js
cy.intercept('/foo', (req) => {
  if (req.body.bar === true) { // or whatever logic indicates the call you want to intercept
    req.alias = 'baz'; // conditionally assign alias
    req.reply({foo: 'bar'}); // mock response
  } else {
    req.continue(); // do not mock response
  }
});

cy.get('something')
  .click()
  .wait('@baz'); // waits for your specific 'baz' call to happen.
```

Comment: Thanks. Still I can't convert the response which is an ArrayBuffer format, to actual js objects. My approach is to use `new TextDecoder().decode(res.body)`, but result is still not what I expected. I updated my question for this.

Comment: Have you tried just using `.toJSON()`?  `res.body.toJSON()`?

Comment: You mean JSON.parse(res.body)? Unfortunately no. Because the response body(res.body) is an ArrayBuffer

Comment: Ah, had my syntax wrong -> something like this possibly? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594294/11625850

Comment: Doesn't work. Because `ArrayBuffer.isView(res.body)` check before executing `Buffer.from(res.body).toJSON()` , returns false(If I don't put that check, I get an error which says: `First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.` when using `Buffer.from(res.body)`). Maybe some kind of grpc client would solve the problem but I don't know how to leverage it