LevelJS when in browser with IndexedDB as a storage shows arrays of bytes instead of JSON or readable object representation
I instantiate and populate the LevelJS abstraction as follows:
import * as level from 'level';
const defDb = new level.Level('def', {valueEncoding: 'json'});
defDb.put(keyObj, valueObj);

and what I see in the browser Developer Tools is
[object ArrayBuffer]:"{"0":123,"1":34,"2":110,"3":97......}"

Both Firefox and Chrome show arraybuffer. The data is retrieved as a good object though, but it's hard to debug.
How can I see the key as a string and the value as an object with fields?
Add: Could involve some database connection parameter to store it differently, or a browser developer tool configuration, either will go for me. I've noticed that when I use IndexedDB without the LevelJS abstraction, the data shows better

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805794/convert-arraybuffer-response-to-json?

Thank you, not really. I can retrieve the object programmatically, it's just I don't see it in the debug interface in a readable format. If I use pure IndexedDB without LevelJS, I see normal objects, so I know it's possible; but I need to debug it with the Level...

The feature you want is not implemented in devtools.

Could there be a leveljs.org connection parameter that makes it store the IndexedDB data as not an ArrayBuffer?
